# How to pass named ranges of different dimensions without #NA error

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

The structure of my workbook is the following: there are UI sheets, calculation sheets, and a database sheet.

- The user interacts with the UI sheets and macros are called from there.
- Information is passed to the calculation sheet (via named range) and the calculation is executed there.
- Outputs from the calculation sheet are passed to the UI sheet (via named range) and the database sheet (also via named range).

When the user "saves" a file, the program is only saving a copy of the database sheet to a new file. This is done so that the user does not overwrite the master file. When the user "opens" a file, that file is retrieved and the data passed from the saved file to the database sheet in the master file via named range.

To populate this database sheet, I pass values from the UI and calculation sheets by the following code:

```
ws_DB.range("rngName_UI").value2 = ws_UI.range("rngName_UI").value2
ws_DB.range("rngName_Calc").value2 = ws_Calc.range("rngName_Calc").value2
```

The only problem with this system is that my named ranges might gain new rows/columns over time if I need to output new information. That means that if I saved a database sheet with version 1 and some named range "rng_A" had 3 columns, but then I retrieve that in version 2 and "rng_A" has 5 columns, then Excel shows the last 2 columns with a #NA error.

Is there a convenient way to avoid this problem? My best idea so far is that I can get the rows and columns of the source and destination range(s) and then pass only to the minimum of the nRows and nCols. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Without seeing the data you process and **the code processing way**, it is difficult for us to clearly understand what is it about and give ideas to solve the problem.  `#N/A` error has a very clear signification. If the (named range) column in discussion does not have correspondence in the existing processing way, it informs the user about the issue. What would you like, in fact? To avoid copying of the named range 'problematic' columns? To clear the resulted cells keeping '#N/A' errors? To adapt formulas/functions processing the range to skip these columns? It is difficult to be helped so...

Comment: Let's say I want to pass information from the UI sheet (ws_UI) in the named range "rng_A" to the database sheet (ws_DB). When I do this, I write the following: ws_DB.Range("rng_A").value2 = ws_UI.Range("rng_A").value2. However, if "rng_A" has 3 columns in the UI sheet and 5 columns in the DB sheet, the last 2 columns will show as #NA in the DB sheet when I pass data from the UI sheet.

Comment: So, you nave the same names in both workbooks/sheets to be handled. A piece of information which I couldn't understand from your question. Now, how do you want to proceed? You can previously check the named ranges addresses and in case of not matching, you can do something. Then, **what would you like doing?** To copy only the matching range? To extend the existing range in a way to be able to receive all the information from the one to be copied? Which is the scope of the named ranges in discussion? The workbook or the worksheet? If the worksheet, are both of them named identically?

Comment: As long as I understand, named range is either a fix area or grow in row which is called dynamic named range (the range box is filled with a formula). In your case, it seems you need the dynamic named range - but I'm sorry I never know a dynamic named range which grow/shrink besides the row also grow/shrink the column. If the UI sheet value that you want to copy to the DB sheet has no blank row and no blank column, maybe you can try to just copy the range. Something like this.....

Comment: `With Sheets("UI")
ofst = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count - 1
Set rg = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown))
Set rg = Range(rg, rg.Offset(0, ofst))
rg.Copy Destination:=Sheets("DB").Range("A1")
End With` Then name the range via VBA also.